# Return id on next "page" in single page site based on current page id using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a simple website which should have multiple pages showing a different background and main text, but with the same logo and menu. The next page should slide in from the right when a button is pressed and selecting a page from the menu should transition directly to that page. I have decided to make this a single page site to make use of CSS3 transitions. Example code for the next button (minus transitions) is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xoa029jz/1/

I am currently working out which background and text to display using the following javascript:

```
function getNextPage(pageid) {
    if (pageid == "page-1") {
        return $('#page-2');
    } else if (pageid == "page-2") {
        return $('#page-3');
    } else if (pageid == "page-3") {
        return $('#page-1');
    }
}
```

The site will have 7 pages, so this seems cumbersome. Is there a better way of using sequential ids in javascript?

The site will only have one image and one sentence per "page", so I don't think it is necessary to use Ajax, but I am willing to be corrected on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class in this case which will not bound you for any number of pages,

```
function getNextPage(pageid) {
    if($('.current-page').next('.page-text').length){
        return $('.current-page').next('.page-text');
    }
    return $('.page-text:first');
}
```

```js
function slideToNext() {
    var currentPage = $('.current-page');
    var nextPage = getNextPage(currentPage.attr('id'));
    
    $(currentPage).removeClass('current-page');
    $(nextPage).addClass('current-page');

    var currentBackground = getCurrentBackground();
    var nextBackground = getNextBackground(currentBackground);

    $('#bg').removeClass(currentBackground);
    $('#bg').addClass(nextBackground);
}

function getNextPage(pageid) {
    if($('.current-page').next('.page-text').length){
        return $('.current-page').next('.page-text');
    }
    return $('.page-text:first');
}

function getCurrentBackground() {
    var bg = $('#bg');
    if (bg.hasClass('bg-1')) {
        return "bg-1";
    } else if (bg.hasClass('bg-2')) {
        return "bg-2";
    } else if (bg.hasClass('bg-3')) {
        return "bg-3";
    }
}

function getNextBackground(bg) {
    if (bg == "bg-1") {
        return "bg-2";
    } else if (bg == "bg-2") {
        return "bg-3";
    } else if (bg == "bg-3") {
        return "bg-1";
    }
}
```

```css
.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index:1;
}
.page-text {
    margin-top: 71px;
    display: none;
}
.current-page {
    display: inline;
    visibility: visible;
}
.bg-1 {
    background-color:#D8F6CE;
}
.bg-2 {
    background-color:#CEECF5;
}
.bg-3 {
    background-color:#E2A9F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="page bg-1" id="bg">
    <div id="page">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" width="295" height="92" />
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button>Page 1</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>Page 2</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>Page 3</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="page-text current-page" id="page1">Page 1 text</div>
        <div class="page-text" id="page2">Page 2 text</div>
        <div class="page-text" id="page3">Page 3 text</div>
        <button type="button" onclick="slideToNext()">Next</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted, as I was also trying to avoid editing class names as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Get the ID as a number, and increment it:

```
var num = +pageid[5];
if (num < 7) {
    return $('#page-'+(num+1));
}
return $('#page-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 7 pages, cant u loop it, like:

```
for(var i=0;i<=7;i++){
   if (pageid == "page-"+i) {
      return $('#page-'+i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
 //just remove the word page so that only the number will left (e.g. "page"1 )
 var nextPage = getNextPage(currentPage.attr('id').replace('page', ''));
```

Then your function will be shorter and no element count hard coding.

```
function getNextPage(pageid) {
   return $('#page' + (pageid + 1)); //just take care the logic for returning to first page
}
```